# Webpage keeps prompting to download

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

I have my files hosted on my website. If I have a .php file the page loads fine, however, if I have a .html file with some php in it. EG:

```
<?php include 'nav.php'?>
```

and a `.htaccess` file with:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

The page simply shows up blank in IE, Chrome and Firefox and has a download option for the page. This can be seen [here](http://www.illogicalbit.com/deco1400/obc/index.html). If you download this file, the php is still visible, and has not been run. Does anyone know why this is happening? Does anyone know how to fix it?

NOTE: Other .php files work fine, so PHP is obviously working. Can be seen by going to [here](http://www.illogicalbit.com/index.php)

Comment: Why not just use a .php file instead?

Comment: @Adam I would use a .php file, however this is for a course where we aren't covering PHP (Not allowed to submit PHP files). I would like to use php for my testing phase to include the header/footer/nav etc so i dont have to change all my files if I decide to add a new page.